# Redux and dependent async action

Tags: javascript, redux

Is it a good idea to have dependencies between async actions in Redux ?

If `ACTION_A` and `ACTION_B` are async Redux actions and in order to react to `ACTION_B` we need to have `ACTION_A_SUCCESS` dispatched (so the store contains needed data) then is there a canonical way how to do this in Redux or is this a poor design choice ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `ACTION_B` to be performed after the `ACTION_A`, you should be dispatching the `ACTION_B` in the success/error callback of `ACTION_A`.